# Create a set of files based off a date range

Tags: bash, datetime, automation

How would you go about doing a few lines of code in Bash to accomplish the following. I'm trying to build up my skills in Bash and learn how to handle more small tasks directory from the command line.

Steps:

1. Specify a start date and an end date. Load all the dates in between including the start and end date into a "list"
2. Loop over the list creating a file like this each time. 
   (requires date formatting)

   ```
   2017-11-10.w
   2017-11-11.w
   2017-11-12.w
   ```

Comment: Bash is not that great for managing dates.  I would do it in perl or other more "advanced" language than bash.  My 2 cents.  And what have you tried, what research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the input dates to Unix timestamps, then add the number of seconds per day and `touch` a file named after the result until you are past the end date:

```
#!/bin/bash

startstamp=$(date -d "$1" +'%s')
endstamp=$(date -d "$2" +'%s')

secs_per_day=$(( 24 * 3600 ))

for (( thedate = startstamp; thedate <= endstamp; thedate += secs_per_day )); do
    touch "$(date -d "@$thedate" '+%F.w')"
done
```

The `%s` formatting string (a GNU extension) prints the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, and `@` in the argument to the `-d` option indicates that the date is in that format. `%F` is short for `%Y-%m-%d`, which translates to YYYY-MM-DD.

Example usage:

```
$ ./dates 2017-11-10 2017-11-15
$ ls -1
2017-11-10.w
2017-11-11.w
2017-11-12.w
2017-11-13.w
2017-11-14.w
2017-11-15.w
dates
```